# Remove attr in Cypress still opens me a new window

Tags: cypress, target, attr

So I tried to remove an attribute from this code, but it still shoots me a new window - what could I be doing wrong?

```
cy.visit('https://staging.robo.academy/customers')
        cy.url().should('eql','https://staging.robo.academy/customers')
        cy.wait(5000)
        cy.get('tbody > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(1)').invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()
```

and also, if I want to remove one attr after another, like in the code bellow - what is the solution for that?

```
cy.visit('https://staging.robo.academy/customers')
        cy.url().should('eql','https://staging.robo.academy/customers')
        cy.wait(5000)
        cy.get('tbody > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(1)').invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()
        cy.get('.card-actions > a').invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()
```

Thank you in advance!

I was expecting the tab not to open, but to proceed on the same tab. Still, it opens me new tab and nothing happens. I'm using Cypress 6.8 version, since it does a great job for me.

Comment: You should share the HTML of the element. Are you sure the element  has a `target` attribute?

Comment: Indded, it might not have this attribute....

Comment: I recommend checking how your app deals with opening a new window. Here are a few ways to deal with a second tab/window with cypress.
https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-second-tab/